# Type inference in andThen() in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand how *andThen* works in Scala.

Here's the code:

```
    def collectNames(fromList: List[Map[String,String]]) = {
      fromList.foldLeft(new StringBuffer)((x,y) => {
          x.append(y("Name")).append(",")
      }).toString
    }

    def getOriginalList = List(Map("Name" -> "NS","Age" -> "50"),Map ("Name" -> "SS", "Age" -> "45"))


    getOriginalList andThen collectNames
```

The compiler finds this disagreeable. It seems that *collectNames* is being given a `Map[String,String]` rather than a `List[Map[String,String]]`.

What does it take me to be able to write that little snippet of 'flowing' code correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getOriginalList _` is a `Function0` (i.e `() => R`) and has no `compose` or `andThen`.

Therefore, you this won't compile: `getOriginalList _ andThen collectNames _`

Now if `getOriginalList` can be treated as a partially applied function1, it will work:

```
def getOriginalList(a: Any) = List(Map("Name" -> "NS","Age" -> "50"))
val composed = getOriginalList _ andThen collectNames _
```

But in your case, composition-wise, you should probably consider `getOriginalList` as a `val` and use it as a function argument:

```
def collectNames(fromList: List[Map[String,String]]) = {
  fromList.foldLeft(new StringBuffer)((x,y) => {
      x.append(y("Name")).append(",")
  }).toString
}

def getOriginalList = List(Map("Name" -> "NS","Age" -> "50"),Map ("Name" -> "SS", "Age" -> "45"))

val comp = collectNames _ andThen ((s: String) => s.length())
val n = comp(getOriginalList)   // 6 = ("NS,SS,".length())
```

Comment: many thanks for the explanation. _getOriginalList_ in my code snippet was just an example, quickly written (laziness)! In my actual code, it is indeed a function with some logic. However, I understand why you suggest that it should be passed as a function argument.